# Case sensitivity not maintained while using Textrange.replace

Tags: vba, powerpoint, str-replace, case-sensitive

I hope all are doing well..
I have been trying to develop a small macro which could find certain words from a PowerPoint presentation and replace them with certain other words using the method

```
TextRange.Replace(FindWhat:=FindString, Replacewhat:=ReplaceString, _
                  WholeWords:=True, MatchCase := False)
```

The requirement is that the ReplaceString should have the same case sensitivity as that of the words to be replaced in the presentation. But using the above method, the case of the ReplaceString always remains the same( as defined earlier). I need it to change it as per the case of the FindString from the presentation.

For example, if my FindString is bridge and ReplaceString is brg, in my presentation, if Bridge and BRIDGE comes up, it should be replaced with Brg and BRG respectively ( but with above method, it is replacing Bridge and BRIDGE with brg)

I hope my query has made some sense..

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Will there be only 3 case types (lower, Proper and UPPER) ?  If Yes then you can cycle each term through those cases, set the replacement case to match, and perform the replace using using `MatchCase := True`

Comment: Hi Tim.. thanks for your response.. actually, I am checking for about 6000 words to be replaced if present in the the presentation. If I incorporate these words with different cases, the words would be about 12000 plus. Running a macro for such replacement would take a lot of processing time. This functionality is automatically incorporated when using replace method in MS Word VBA. But sadly the isn't being done when using the method with PowerPoint VBA.

Comment: If it takes too long then for sure try a different appraoch, but probably worth performing some tests to make sure it's "too" slow before you search for another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example.  Before trying any replacements it checks to see if the word is found at all in the textrange: that should resolve some of your performance concerns.  Has the advantage of being able to use `WholeWords:=True` which prevents replacing substrings of longer words.

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim tr As TextRange
    
    Set tr = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
    
    DoReplace tr, "bridge", "brg"
    
End Sub

Sub DoReplace(tr As TextRange, findThis, replaceWith)
    If InStr(1, tr.Text, findThis, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'is the word found at all?
        'found at least one case form - just try to replace any case form found...
        tr.Replace findWhat:=LCase(findThis), Replacewhat:=LCase(replaceWith), _
                  WholeWords:=True, MatchCase:=True
        tr.Replace findWhat:=UCase(findThis), Replacewhat:=UCase(replaceWith), _
                  WholeWords:=True, MatchCase:=True
        tr.Replace findWhat:=StrConv(findThis, vbProperCase), _
                   Replacewhat:=StrConv(replaceWith, vbProperCase), _
                  WholeWords:=True, MatchCase:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim. I probably misunderstood your comment earlier. Checking for word's case and then performing the replace is certainly what I require. Regarding the performance, although I ll have to run few more lines to include the approach suggested by you, I think it wouldn't have that significant effect. Let me try this and give you the feedback. Thanks again Tim. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Tim, I implemented the sub in my code. It works fine without any excessive processing time. It exactly doesthe job required. Thanks again.Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this, but not with `.Replace`. It is necessary to separate the steps of finding and replacing, so that between the two you can inspect what is found and then replace with a similar text case (e.g. upper, lower or 'proper').

The key is to use the [InStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) function, because it allows you to find with any text case, while also allowing you to set the find start index and return the index of the match found - so that you can go through each match, one at a time, in a loop. Then, to find the text case, loop through each character of the match, count upper and lower; and replace accordingly.

```vb
Public Function ReplaceMatchCase(str, find, replace) As String
    Dim lenStr As Long
    Dim lenFind As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim countUpper As Long
    Dim countLower As Long
    Dim chr As String
    
    i = 1
    lenStr = Len(str)
    lenFind = Len(find)
    
    If lenFind = 0 Or lenStr = 0 Or lenStr < lenFind Then
        ReplaceMatchCase = str
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'Loop through each match
    Do
        i = InStr(i, str, find, vbTextCompare)
        
        If i = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        countUpper = 0
        countLower = 0
        
        'Loop through chars in each match
        For j = i To i + lenFind - 1
            chr = Mid(str, j, 1)
            If chr = UCase(chr) Then
                countUpper = countUpper + 1
            Else
                countLower = countLower + 1
            End If
        Next j
        
        'Replace
        If countUpper <> 0 And countLower = 0 Then
            'Uppercase
            str = Mid(str, 1, i - 1) & UCase(replace) & Mid(str, i + lenFind)
        
        ElseIf countUpper = 0 And countLower <> 0 Then
            'Lowercase
            str = Mid(str, 1, i - 1) & LCase(replace) & Mid(str, i + lenFind)
        
        Else
            'Mixed - assume 'proper' case - can change this according to need
            str = Mid(str, 1, i - 1) & UCase(Mid(replace, 1, 1)) & LCase(Mid(replace, 2)) & Mid(str, i + lenFind)
        End If
        
    Loop While i <> 0
    
    ReplaceMatchCase = str
End Function
```

You can test the function like this:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print ReplaceMatchCase("I walked to the furthest bridge and on the way I passed the first BRIDGE and the second Bridge.", "Bridge", "Brg")
End Sub

'I walked to the furthest brg and on the way I passed the first BRG and the second Brg.
```

From PowerPoint, you would use the function like this:

```vb
TextRange.Text = ReplaceMatchCase(TextRange.Text, FindString, ReplaceString)
```

Comment: I also understand separating find and replace is essential as per my requirement. I am pretty sure that the suggested code would do the trick. Let me include your approach in my macro and give you the feedback. Thanks sb. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Sbgib, i tried with the function mentioned. It does the job intended. But it also converts the nested words. For example, if I have defined bridge as well to be replaced as rig, it changes Bridge as Brig, which isnt the right replacement. The method suggested by Tim doesnt do it as it is using matchcase attribute. Also, since it is parsing over all the letters, it is taking more time to process. For Now, Solution by @Tim does the job for me. But really, thanks for helping me. Cheers!

Comment: That's fine. You're welcome :) I agree with you, the other solution is more peformant and elegant - so I learnt something too! That's the beauty of SO ;)